# How to call methods on objects that I didn't assign a reference name to?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jpanel, jbutton

For example, I am trying to call the `setEnable` method on a `JButton` that I constructed within the parameter parenthesis of an add method:

```
add(new JButton());
```

I know I could just do something like:

```
JButton button = new JButton();
button.setEnable(false);
```

but is there I way I can call `setEnable` on a `JButton` that I didn't assign a reference name to?

The reason why I am not assigning the JButton a reference name is because I am supposed to add an unknown number of JButtons to a JPanel. How I am doing this, is by using this for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfButtonsToAdd; i++) 
{
   JPanelName.add(new JButton());
}
```

and I want all the JButtons to be disabled.

Comment: Short answer: you can't if you want to assign the instance to something like add().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You state in comment:

> The reason why I am not assigning the JButton a reference name is because I am supposed to add an unknown number of JButtons to a JPanel. How I am doing this, is by using a for loop: for (int i = 0; i < numberOfButtonsToAdd; i++) { JPanelName.add(new JButton()); }

Then just use either an array or ArrayList of JButton.

```
// in your field declarations
List<JButton> buttonList = new ArrayList<JButton>();

// elsewhere in your program
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfButtonsToAdd; i++) { 
  JButton button = new JButton();
  buttonList.add(button);
  somePanel.add(button); 
}
```

Now you have a reference to any button in the list via `buttonList.get(someIndex)`

Note also, that most buttons are given ActionListeners that are activated whenever the button is pressed. Without such listeners, the buttons are pretty much useless. You can also get a reference to the pressed JButton from the ActionListener via the ActionEvent object passed into its actionPerformed method:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   AbstractButton myButton = (AbstractButton) e.getSource();
   // now you can use myButton
}
```

Note that this is key information that you should have shared with us up front in your original question.

---

**Edit** 
You state now:

> and I want all the JButtons to be disabled.

Then just make them disabled from the get-go:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfButtonsToAdd; i++) { 
  JButton button = new JButton();
  button.setEnabled(false);
  buttonList.add(button);
  somePanel.add(button); 
}
```

Although I am curious -- why all disabled? Why no ActionListener? No text?

---

**Edit 2**
You state:

> Would I still be able to access those individual buttons later on, since they are all assigned "button"?

Please understand that the variable name is of little importance, and in fact, in my example above, the variable named button does not exist outside of the for loop within which it was declared. Instead what matters is the ***reference*** to the JButton object. As has been much discussed in the other answers and as you are aware, this can be obtained by using a variable, but it doesn't have to be a variable directly to the JButton, it could, as is in this case, be the variable to the `ArrayList<JButton>`. That's why I suggest that you create this entity.

---

**Edit 3**
for example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;

public class ButtonLists extends JPanel {
   private static final int ROWS = 6;
   private static final int COLS = 6;
   private List<JButton> allButtons = new ArrayList<JButton>();
   private List<JButton> evenButtons = new ArrayList<JButton>();

   public ButtonLists() {
      JPanel gridPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLS));
      for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            int buttonInt = i * COLS + j;
            String buttonString = String.valueOf(buttonInt);
            JButton button = new JButton(buttonString);
            button.setEnabled(false);
            gridPanel.add(button);
            allButtons.add(button);
            if (buttonInt % 2 == 0) {
               evenButtons.add(button);
            }
         }
      }

      JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
      bottomPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Activate All") {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (JButton btn : allButtons) {
               btn.setEnabled(true);
            }
         }
      }));
      bottomPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Activate Even") {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (JButton btn : allButtons) {
               btn.setEnabled(false);
            }
            for (JButton btn : evenButtons) {
               btn.setEnabled(true);
            }
         }
      }));
      bottomPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Activate Odd") {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (JButton btn : allButtons) {
               btn.setEnabled(true);
            }
            for (JButton btn : evenButtons) {
               btn.setEnabled(false);
            }
         }
      }));

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(gridPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("ButtonLists");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new ButtonLists());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: I apologize for not being too clear, but thank you very much for your help! I am making a simple app where the all the buttons will be disabled at first, but then become enabled after certain buttons from another panel are pressed. There will be actionListeners involved, but I haven't gotten there just yet. I also do have an ArrayList with names of what each button should be called, but I didn't think it was necessary to mention it. I do still have a question about your for loop though. Would I still be able to access those individual buttons later on, since they are all assigned "button"?

Comment: @GrangerLang: see Edit 3 for an example

Answer (score 3):

If you added it to a panel you can get the components of that panel and looping through those components if one is a button you could call `setEnabled(`), but if there were more than one button you would have to determine if it was the correct one.

**Edit**:

Since you added that you want all the buttons disabled then this method should work nicely. Examples:

All:

```
        for(Component  c : panel.getComponents()){
            c.setEnabled(false);
        }
```

Just JButtons:

```
        for(Component  c : panel.getComponents()){
            if(c instanceof JButton){
                ((JButton)c).setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am indeed adding it to a JPanel, and all that I'm adding to that JPanel is JButtons added with "JPanelName.add(new JButton());". How do I get a particular button? Thanks.

Comment: @GrangerLang: you're not explaining why you decline to assign the JButton to a JButton variable. Your question is very incomplete to say the least. Please explain more why you can't simply use a variable. Consider showing more pertinent parts of your code.

Comment: @GrangerLang, updated my answer since you now say you want all items disabled.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. If `setEnabled()` returned the object it's enabling, you could enable-and-add the object in a single line. But as it is, `setEnabled()` returns `void`, so you have no choice but to use a local variable.

However, a  `JButton` is enabled by default, so there's no need to explicitly call  `setEnabled()`  on it, it's already enabled!

Answer (score 0):

The only way this can work is if what ever you are adding it to has a get method. other than that you don't have any other options. Best way is what you showed.

```
JButton button = new JButton();
button.setEnable(true);
```

Comment: setEnable() does not exists. setEnabled(boolean) does.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a method in a new instance like

```
new JButton().setEnabled(true);
```

But this won't allow you to access the `JButton` instance you create here anymore and thus you cannot call `add()`.

This can only be possible if the method call returns the instance object on which it was called. So if for example `setEnabled` would return the same instance on which it was called (that is, `this` in `setEnabled` context) , you could do `add(new JButton().setEnabled(true))`.

Anyway in your case don't be afraid of using references:

```
final JButton button = new JButton();
button.setEnabled(true);
add(button);
```

Note that in this case 2 last methods can be called in any order, the result will be the same.

Comment: nothing somehow better in compare with your comment to another answer here